# How to check/know the highest run queries

Tags: postgresql, view, materialized-view

I would like to gather statistics on the highest run queries in my database.

For that I need to know how I can track queries so I can create views or materialized views to cache the results of the highest run queries since I have a big DB.

Comment: Have you checked [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Monitoring)?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html

Comment: Out of curiosity, how big is big?  Also, by 'highest run' do you mean the most often run or the cumulatively most expensive queries?  And, with a simple view, you don't spare anything in this regard.

Comment: @ dezso: it is 300k rows on main table. The most expensive would be a priority but i also want to know the most often run.

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name already said .. the pg_stat_statements extension is probably what you need.

Comment: You can also `set log_statement to all;`.  This will produce a nice big log file, but you won't miss any of your queries.

Answer (score 18):

As someone said in the comments, [pg_stat_statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html) is the way to get the statistics. Put this into your `postgresql.conf`:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'

pg_stat_statements.max = 10000
pg_stat_statements.track = all
```

Then run this query:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;
```

After that, this sample query (copied from the docs linked above) will give you the stats for 5 top queries from **all the databases**:

```
SELECT query, calls, total_time, rows,
100.0 * shared_blks_hit / nullif(shared_blks_hit + shared_blks_read, 0) AS hit_percent
FROM pg_stat_statements ORDER BY total_time DESC LIMIT 5;
```

If you want results for a **single database**, you need to filter by `dbid` which you can get from `pg_database` by db name. Add this WHERE clause to the query above:

```
WHERE dbid = (select oid from pg_database where datname = 'YOUR_DB_NAME')
```

You could also do a join.

When you're testing this it may be a good idea to exclude the queries to the stats/schema tables themselves, for example:

```
AND query not similar to '%( pg_|information_schema)%'
```

There's [a bunch of free and commercial tools](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Monitoring) that can help you visualize the data.

Comment: Nowadays (postgres 14) there is no `total_time` in there, but there is `total_exec_time`